# What is the difference between my own implementation of Redux store using thunks and RTK query?

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I'm reading through the RTK query guide and I find it as an abstraction instead of using hooks to make thunks and selectors the longer way. If I would use RTK query to retrieve data and store them in the redux store what would be the point of implementing my own using thunks and createSlice...

Comment: "my own implementation of redux store" sounds dangerously like you're re-implementing redux itself. Might want to phrase the question differently.

Comment: It's not clear. What do you want to implement by yourself?